# mkfs.vfat not found on GuixSD

Tags: vfat, guix, guixsd

Troubles formatting usb-flash under GuixSD, cause it cannot find mkfs.vfat.

I've installed dosfstools but util-linux installation shows some another stuff.

```
# guix package -i dosfstools
The following package will be upgraded:
   dosfstools   4.1 → 4.1   /gnu/store/4im5hyda53qjnkc869m0fxdi7dm5f0lg-dosfstools-4.1

nothing to be done

# guix package -i util-linux
The following package will be upgraded:
   util-linux   2.32 → 2.32 /gnu/store/fbaawq3xvpqpnj4rdhbiq8kmkmf6biqv-util-linux-2.32

substitute: updating list of substitutes from 'https://mirror.hydra.gnu.org'... substitute: updating list of substitutes from 'https://mirror.hydra.gnu.org'... 100.0%
The following derivations will be built:
   /gnu/store/ml5l1q5k3law12k0wzwhm99wbrhsbfsh-profile.drv
   /gnu/store/xp95dbp21vy2an0rjrzfq5askywn9xsc-fonts-dir.drv
   /gnu/store/w161mxr5ilqavkgd90gl2f5pfz92nlk1-info-dir.drv
   /gnu/store/q4bp45cm6nnjjmk14cpy7kfklaq3j4wv-ca-certificate-bundle.drv
   /gnu/store/nm2iv9g5kjg5bb344n6p8c7aha5k8dvj-gtk-im-modules.drv
   /gnu/store/bi0wh6qa9c1l065d33nbfazd8kn5bprh-xdg-desktop-database.drv
   /gnu/store/6j4m52dc2fdz8sj88crr8i5vi39m2bzc-gtk-icon-themes.drv
   /gnu/store/68jwfnbz1nhczf2lg7jnklp9bzk7avls-glib-schemas.drv
   /gnu/store/0hp1w4nsxq288s5p9lwxqcfpnrr9r9sn-xdg-mime-database.drv
   /gnu/store/lzjilc0nallyk6k1lnk0v97y2af49mfk-manual-database.drv
No schema files found: doing nothing.
Creating manual page database...
146 entries processed in 0.5 s
9 packages in profile

# whereis mkfs |grep vfat
#
# whereis mkfs
mkfs: /gnu/store/lbbmdb8q34bxggkvsidi4j9hiyw3flv2-profile/sbin/mkfs.cramfs /gnu/store/lbbmdb8q34bxggkvsidi4j9hiyw3flv2-profile/sbin/mkfs.bfs /gnu/store/lbbmdb8q34bxggkvsidi4j9hiyw3flv2-profile/sbin/mkfs.fat /gnu/store/lbbmdb8q34bxggkvsidi4j9hiyw3flv2-profile/sbin/mkfs.minix /gnu/store/lbbmdb8q34bxggkvsidi4j9hiyw3flv2-profile/sbin/mkfs /gnu/store/pqkqim2q4sygx9nf02ajbcy8zwr6c80v-profile/sbin/mkfs.ext4 /gnu/store/pqkqim2q4sygx9nf02ajbcy8zwr6c80v-profile/sbin/mkfs.ext2 /gnu/store/pqkqim2q4sygx9nf02ajbcy8zwr6c80v-profile/sbin/mkfs.cramfs /gnu/store/pqkqim2q4sygx9nf02ajbcy8zwr6c80v-profile/sbin/mkfs.bfs /gnu/store/pqkqim2q4sygx9nf02ajbcy8zwr6c80v-profile/sbin/mkfs.minix /gnu/store/pqkqim2q4sygx9nf02ajbcy8zwr6c80v-profile/sbin/mkfs.ext3 /gnu/store/pqkqim2q4sygx9nf02ajbcy8zwr6c80v-profile/sbin/mkfs

# mkfs -t vfat /dev/sdb1
mkfs: failed to execute mkfs.vfat: No such file or directory
```

Sorry? Why all another filesystems present but vfat does not?

mkdosfs does not work too:

```
mkdosfs -F 32 -I /dev/sdb1
bash: mkdosfs: command not found
```

How to format to Fat 32 under GuixSD? I want just to burn flash with linux-iso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to format to Fat 32 under GuixSD?

You should use the following command:

```
mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/sdb
```

The command `mkfs.vfat` is  deprecated (old) according to the [source package](https://github.com/dosfstools/dosfstools), (check `guix package -s dosfstools` to get the package source).

To get the command `mkfs.vfat` again you should rebuild the package with the `--enable-compat-symlinks` option:

> The `./configure` script has an option `--enable-compat-symlinks` **that will configure the build to symlink older names of the tools** to the current ones on installation. These are dosfsck, fsck.msdos and fsck.vfat for fsck.fat, mkdosfs, mkfs.msdos and **mkfs.vfat** for mkfs.fat and dosfslabel for fatlabel.

once done, the command `mkfs.vfat` will work and the `mkfs` will accept the `vfat` option.